# How to pass variables to other html?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a quiz wherein I am trying to count and add up the scores in 10 different html files. How do I do it? What I want is for the scores to add +1 when it is correct or just retain if it is wrong and show the score as a message, but I am having problems since they are in different html files.

This is my script on the first html file:

```js
var g;
var h;
var i;
var j;

function submit001() {
  b = input001.value;
  c = input002.value;
  d = input003.value;
  e = input004.value;
  if (b == "(~ M > Q) ^ (R > ~ T)" || b == "(~M>Q)^(R>~T)") {
    g = 1;
    input001.value = b;
    check001.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✔" + "</text>";
  } else {
    input001.value = b;
    check001.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✖" + "</text>";
  }

  if (c == "1, 2, Conj" || c == "1,2,Conj") {
    h = 1
    input002.value = c;
    check002.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✔" + "</text>";
  } else {
    input002.value = c;
    check002.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✖" + "</text>";
  }

  if (d == "Q v ~ T" || d == "Qv~T") {
    i = 1;
    input003.value = d;
    check003.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✔" + "</text>";
  } else {
    input003.value = d;
    check003.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✖" + "</text>";
  }

  if (e == "3, 4, CD" || e == "3,4,CD") {
    j = 1;
    input004.value = e;
    check004.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✔" + "</text>";
  } else {
    input004.value = e;
    check004.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✖" + "</text>";
  }

  if (g == 1 && h == 1 && i == 1 && j == 1) {
    var score1 = 0;
    var score = score1 + 1;
  } else {
    var score = 0;

  }
  message001.innerHTML = "Your score is" + " " + score;
  disappear001.innerHTML = "";
  reload001.innerHTML = "<div id=center001><button class=button001 onclick=next001()>Next</button></div>";
}


function next001() {
  window.location.replace("Question2.html")
}
```

This the script on the second one

```js
var p;
var q;
var r;
var s;
var t;
var u;
var v;
var w;

function submit001() {
  x = input001.value;
  y = input002.value;
  z = input003.value;
  a = input004.value;
  b = input005.value;
  c = input006.value;
  d = input007.value;
  e = input008.value;
  if (x == "D ^ W" || x == "D^W") {
    p = 1;
    input001.value = x;
    check001.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✔" + "</text>";
  } else {
    input001.value = x;
    check001.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✖" + "</text>";
  }

  if (y == "1, 3, MP" || y == "1,3,MP") {
    q = 1
    input002.value = y;
    check002.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✔" + "</text>";
  } else {
    input002.value = y;
    check002.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✖" + "</text>";
  }

  if (z == "D" || z == "D") {
    r = 1;
    input003.value = z;
    check003.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✔" + "</text>";
  } else {
    input003.value = z;
    check003.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✖" + "</text>";
  }

  if (a == "4, Simp" || a == "4,Simp") {
    s = 1;
    input004.value = a;
    check004.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✔" + "</text>";
  } else {
    input004.value = a;
    check004.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✖" + "</text>";
  }
  if (b == "K" || b == "K") {
    t = 1;
    input005.value = b;
    check005.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✔" + "</text>";
  } else {
    input005.value = b;
    check005.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✖" + "</text>";
  }
  if (c == "2, 5, MP" || c == "2,5,MP") {
    u = 1;
    input006.value = c;
    check006.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✔" + "</text>";
  } else {
    input006.value = c;
    check006.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✖" + "</text>";
  }

  if (d == "N ^ K" || d == "N^K") {
    v = 1;
    input007.value = d;
    check007.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✔" + "</text>";
  } else {
    input007.value = d;
    check007.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✖" + "</text>";
  }
  if (e == "3, 6, Conj" || e == "3,6,Conj") {
    w = 1;
    input008.value = e;
    check008.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✔" + "</text>";
  } else {
    input008.value = e;
    check008.innerHTML = "<text class=button002>" + "✖" + "</text>";
  }
  if (p == 1 && q == 1 && r == 1 && s == 1 && t == 1 && u == 1 && v == 1 && w == 1) {
    var score1 = score
    var score = score1 + 1;

  } else {
    var score1 = score
    var score = score1 + 0;
  }
  message001.innerHTML = "Your score is" + " " + score;
  disappear001.innerHTML = "";
  reload001.innerHTML = "<div id=center001><button class=button001 onclick=next001()>Next</button></div>";
}


function next001() {
  window.location.replace("Question3.html")
}
```

Comment: Why don't you instead use the hash which can be parsed and used in the script?

Comment: By hash I mean for example www.google.com/search#5 (the #5 is the hash)

Comment: Sorry, I am new to programming and I don't really know how to use hash.

Comment: be lazy! at the top of the submit001 function declare srcText = [ '<text class="button002">', '</text>' ] and then use that all the time below .. like: check008.innerHTML = srcText[0] + "✖"+ srcText[1]; .. then whenever you change that wrapper you only need to change it once ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the location hash then access with `window.location.hash`:

```js
window.location.assign('/Question2.html#correct');
```

Then in script two:

```js
let score = 0;
if (window.location.hash == '#correct') score = 1;
```

I'm just giving an example, but that's how it works. The `#` denotes a hash.
We also use `window.location.assign` instead of `replace` because it is more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have 2 different html files , file1html anf file2hmtl

```html
<a href='page1.html?myVar1=42'>link 1</a>
<a href='page2.html?myVar1=43'>link 2</a>
```

By making sure this goes somewhere around the bottom of your code of the first page and the going to page2 and adding the following jquery code

```js
var qs = new Querystring();
var v1 = qs.get("myVar1");
```

you should be able to get it to work as it should

Answer (score 0):

you should NOT use POST/GET to transfer the score from one page to another; nor will using cookies be safe - a crafty user will simply give themselves the score they like! you should have a backend that stores this information in a session.

Since you repeatedly are doing checks like:

```
if (c == "1, 2, Conj" || c == "1,2,Conj")
```

you should probably simply strip the spaces from the user input.

```
let comparable_c = c.replace( / /g, "" );
```